# No keyboard layout switch after reboot

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, applet, capslock

Since the "Applications -> Settings -> XFCE Settings Manager -> Keyboard" dialogue does not allow to assign a new key for the "Change keyboard layout" action, I have added a "Keyboard layouts" plugin to the upper panel (near the clock).

It lets me to assign <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the change layout action.

But unfortunately, each time after I reboot, the following happens:

- the "keyboard layouts" applet disappears from the upper panel;
- I can not use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to change the layouts on the keyboard anymore.

How can it be fixed?

P.S. My system is Xubuntu 10.04 LTS, 2.6.32-40-generic

Answer (score -1):

1. Settings Manager - Keyboard - Layout. Uncheck "Use system defaults".
2. http://ubuntu.sabza.org/2006/10/13/xubuntu-easily-switch-keyboard-layout/

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It appears to be a bug the OP is describing.

Answer (score -1):

I worked around this problem by changing the [System Default Keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/q/153115/29097). This works on a single-user system (or system where everyone will use the same keyboard) just fine.