# Ubuntu standard keyboard shortcuts work only in English layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 15 and I faced a problem that keyboard shortcuts (such as simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) work only at English keyboard layout. This problem was discussed many times on the Internet, and one of the solution is to set **English layout as default** but in my Ubuntu I can't find this setting. Can I solve this problem at all?

Comment: please refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153115/how-do-i-change-the-system-default-keyboard)

Comment: @Ravan doesn't help me, I tried