# Problem installing ubuntu core on RPi3

Tags: configuration, ubuntu-core

I recently downloaded Ubuntu core from the official Ubuntu site (26/01/20) as
I am trying to install Ubuntu core on my Raspberry Pi 3+ for my first time ever. I have setup an Ubuntu account and transferred my SSH key into it as requested. 
Unfortunately after copying the img to my SD card and booting my Pi, during the configure stage I am unable to generate a '@' key stroke for entering my email address. However all the aplhanumeric keys, the enter key, tab key, '-', '=', and '.' keys provide an output into the Email address box. 
I have tried multiple keyboards in multiple USB slots on the Pi.
I was wondering is there a specific type of keyboard I should be using or not, or is there issue during installation with recognising specific keyboard?

Many thanks for any assistance you can give me

Dave B

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration, then select your favourite layout. Duplicated question of https://askubuntu.com/questions/153115/how-do-i-change-the-system-default-keyboard/194105, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when Core is first configured it is unaware of regional Keyboard_layout types. As I'm using a UK keyboard type, the " key and the @ are swapped with respect to the US keyboard. Therefore I simply needed to press Shift+2 to get the @ character. 
For more details reference [Keyboard layout - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout).

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. A menu to configure the layout should appear. This [guide](http://www.userk.co.uk/keyboard-configuration-using-linux/) shows the process